# Use HVite without vocabulary

Tags: speech-recognition, speech, hidden-markov-models, vocabulary, htk

Is it possible to use HVite from HTK without specifying vocabulary file? I'm doing pure phone recognition and have only phone-level lab files corresponding to speech wavs. I haven't defined any vocab file...

Answer (score 0):

You still need a vocabulary file. Define a dummy small vocabulary where each phone maps to itself.